# What is wrong with my solr account?

Tags: apache, csv, solr, lucene

I am trying to get familiar solr to eventually complete a school project that involves indexing a .csv file. I am following the instructions on the following website: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_4_1/quickstart.html
and in particular, under the section Indexing CSV (Comma/Column Separated Values). I entered the commands just as specified (except im using solr version 6.3.0) and getting constant errors.

Below is what I entered into terminal:

```
Tylers-MacBook-Pro:6.3.0 tyler$ solr start
Archiving 1 old GC log files to /usr/local/Cellar/solr/6.3.0/server/logs/archived
Archiving 1 console log files to /usr/local/Cellar/solr/6.3.0/server/logs/archived
Rotating solr logs, keeping a max of 9 generations
Waiting up to 180 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [-]  
Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=20594). Happy searching!

Tylers-MacBook-Pro:6.3.0 tyler$ bin/post -c gettingstarted example/exampledocs/books.csv
java -classpath /usr/local/Cellar/solr/6.3.0/libexec/dist/solr-core-6.3.0.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=gettingstarted -Ddata=files org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool example/exampledocs/books.csv
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file books.csv (text/csv) to [base]
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/gettingstarted/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 (Not Found) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update?commit=true
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/gettingstarted/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
Time spent: 0:00:00.199
Tylers-MacBook-Pro:6.3.0 tyler$
```

What exactly is going on? All I have done is followed exactly what I was supposed to do. Thanks for any help.

Comment: after you starting Solr, could you check if the gettingstarted created? You could check it on admin page

Comment: I checked http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/ and it just says: HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /solr/gettingstarted/. Reason:

    Not Found

Comment: is there a better way to check it? Sorry, I am a noob with this

Comment: Have you created core "gettingstarted" successfully. ?

Comment: First check if your a folder by the name of `gettingstarted` is present in `server/solr` folder. If it is, check if the folder has a `conf` folder which contains the `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` files. Additionally also check the `server/logs` folder for the log which has this exception and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **bin/solr start -e techproducts**. And then use **techproducts** instead of **gettingstarted**. There is no **gettingstarted** collection anymore and the **techproducts** is the nearest one.

What you've done is started a server with no collections in it at all. So you could also create a collection there, but you would need the right configuration to bootstrap it. So, the first method might be a bit easier at this point.

Comment: I have done this and it has worked for the example that I am trying to test. Thank you very much. My ultimate goal is to have a website where a user enters a keyword into a search bar and then I will use Solr to search the .csv file for the keyword(s). Do you have any insight on linking the search bar (using html) with solr?

Comment: That's a different question. But most cases, you do not expose Solr directly to HTML/user, as that is not secure. You would use a middle-layer such as Spring (Java), Ruby on Rails or NodeJS to implement your business logic and talk to Solr. So, you need to decide on your stack and then search for ideas/examples in that. There is no generic answer.